# ROC and AUC using perfcurve and SVM (fitcsvm) in matlab

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, roc

In the [perfcurve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html#bunsogv-scores)  function of matlab, it uses three arguments,

```
[X,Y,T,AUC] = perfcurve(labels,scores,posclass)
```

labels are the truth ground lables, scores are  returned by the classifier, and the positive class,

In my case, I have two classes, labeled as:  1 (pos class) and 2 (neg calss), 
I am using [SVM](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrsvm.html) classifier,  it returns scores of two columns, and from what I understand is that the first column is the negative class while the second one is the positive class? (as explained here)

[image]

So the syntax sould be as follows?

```
[SVMX,SVMY,T,AUC] = perfcurve(lables, SVM_scores(:,2),1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default settings in function`fitsvm`, order the classes as the first class as the negative and the second class as the positive. so it translates 1 is negative and 2 is positive:
and according to that order, the syntax should be
`[SVMX,SVMY,T,AUC] = perfcurve(lables, SVM_scores(:,1),1);`

or name/varible `'ClassNames',[2,1],` could be used to re-order the classes

`svmModel = fitcsvm(X,Y,'ClassNames',[2,1],'KernelFunction','RBF');`
and thus

```
 [SVMX,SVMY,T, AUC] = perfcurve(lables,SVM_scores(:,2),1);
```